# Email aliases on Windows Live Domains for custom domains

Tags: office-365

I have hosted my email on Google Apps and was trying to move it to Windows Live Domains. However, when I tried to create my email address as `me@mydomain.com` I received the error:

> The requested account name is already in use or was used in the past and has not been through the required waiting period to re-use.

Is there a restriction on Windows Live Domains to create a short alias?

As I have already been using this email address, I really need to create it on Windows Live Domains or not make the switch at all.

Comment: I closed this question because it's about administering a service. It might be on-topic in [webmasters.se] or [sf]. Please checkout their tour thoroughly before asking a question.

Answer (score 1):

The issue I had that sounds like yours was that I did actually create an "alias" to my custom domain email address under my Live account. I was trying to "link" the accounts, but it created the alias. I found that under my account settings / permissions, and was able to delete it there, and then immediately create my custom domain email address.

(However, I did abandon using Windows Live domains for email hosting, because they do not support a catch all address, even if you disable public signups.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you created me@urdomain.com in google app... Remove the google MX records completely and wait for two hours ( max) and then try adding or delete that email id in google app dashboard and then try

There is no restriction to use short alias... am also facing the same issue when migrating form google app, Now its working fine me@as_.in

Comment: Ok. Does disabling work as well as deleting? I've tried just disabling for now. If I'm still unable to create the account, then I'll delete. Didn't want to lose the email, in case I go back. Thanks for the information. MS support is absent. Ugh!

Comment: did u tried by removing all the google mx records

Comment: I removed the mx records of google, added the live domains and waited for hours. In fact, when it still wasn't working last night I decided to let it ride until this morning. Still no. I finally gave up because I do get mail at that email address and how long can I keep it offline? So, I am back on Google Apps again.

Comment: for me Mx record updated with in 15 mins but it took 3 days to create a email id